# Scala-Cannot decrement the for loop

Tags: scala, for-loop, decrement

```
  def start(digit:Int)
  {
    var max = "9"*digit.toInt
    var min = "1"+"0"*(digit-1).toInt

    for(i <- max to min by -1){
                 . . ^ (type mismatch; found : String required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,Char,?])


      var front = i
    }



  }
```

It says type "mismatch ;found:Stringrequired:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,Char,?]"

Comment: max and min are both Strings, did you mean them to be Ints?

Comment: Yes I convert it to Int.

Comment: Once you make them ints it will work

Comment: ok..i'll try other thing.

Comment: Please never try doing this in scala for the sake of the language and the name it bears

Comment: Why?Is it too long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need brackets:

```
var max = ("9" * digit).toInt
var min = ("1"+"0"*(digit-1)).toInt
```

Comment: I figured it out..Thank for the help!

Comment: @O.Chounry If an answer works for you, you can _accept_ it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to refrain from using Strings in the first place - looks like using `Math.pow` is a more direct representation of what you're trying to achieve:

```
val max = Math.pow(10, digit) - 1 // e.g. 9999.0 for digit = 4
val min = Math.pow(10, digit - 1) // e.g. 1000.0 for digit = 4
```